# open ball of a limit point in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose we are given a metric space $(X,d)$ with infinitely many elements whose set of isolated points $A$ in $X$ is finite.

Given a point $x \notin A$, we have that $x$ is a limit point. Does there exist some $r>0$ such that both $B_r(x)$ and $(B_r(x))^c$ are infinite?

Any help would be appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Can you find another point $y\ne x$ such that $y$ is a limit point?

Comment: @JohnDouma I can see how that's gonna help the argument but I'm not sure how to find such $y$.

Comment: How many points are not isolated?

Comment: @JohnDouma I see. Thanks!